# file_get_html returning bizarre symbols

Tags: php, web-scraping

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.vegasinsider.com/mlb/odds/las-vegas/?s=316");

echo $html;
```

$html is returned as a bunch of strnage symbols that include vۺ�(

I though that using:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

would help, but it didn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `html_entity_decode`.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: What character encoding is it on your page? The page you linked to has ISO-8859-1.

Comment: The character encoding isn't specified on my page. It's not html. It's strictly php.

Comment: @Lance, yes ok it's php, but output must have some encoding. If you haven't defined it explicitly it would still have some character-encoding (that is set default). Can you see the character-encoding of the source php-code? (through your ide)

Comment: @Lance - My guess is that your php-source-file is utf8 and the external link is iso-8859-1. That might be why the strange characters are shown when outputted to the browswer because php uses utf8.

Comment: I tried this with no luck. echo mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = 'http://www.vegasinsider.com/mlb/odds/las-vegas/?s=316';
$html = str_get_html(utf8_encode(file_get_contents($url)));

echo $html;
```

Comment: @Lance Edited. How about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$encoded = htmlentities(utf8_encode(file_get_html('yoururl')));
echo $encoded;
```

It will convert the special characteres to HTML entity.

Please see the doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: Doesn't echo anything. It's just a plain white page.

Comment: var_dump returns string(0)

Comment: Please try my edit, I added `utf8_encode` function inside `htmlentities`.

Comment: Corrupted page content ? You really should "force" all page to be UTF-8 so.

Comment: How can I force the page to be UTF-8?

Comment: Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809931/how-to-force-utf-8-encoding-in-browser) for example.. Encode your database as UTF-8, and in all your pages `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: I have that header at the top of my page. I mentioned that in the question.

Comment: And I mentioned in **ALL** your pages. So, the pages you're requesting with `file_get_html` and the page which call that function.

Comment: Well, if the page I'm requesting doesn't have the charset to UTF-8, does that mean I should just try a different URL?

Comment: Nope, but that's always boring to work with some different encodings.. Btw, please look at the code of Wordpress, some months ago I found code which converts all characters (accents, specials one, etc) but I don't have the time to find it out now.. That could maybe solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` is screwy sometimes. Change the code in `simple_html_dom.php` to use `gzopen` instead. Under `file_get_html()`

```
//$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);

//get the contents of the page
$fp = gzopen($url,'r');

$contents = '';

while($html = gzread($fp , 256000))
{
    $contents .= $html;
}

gzclose($fp);
```