# Browser display german language character issue

Tags: jquery, html, character-encoding, meta-tags

my issue is i am displaying german language character and my browser convert some character in question mark symbol. [image]

I have added image here you can see what is exact issue.

I have tried meta tag also like

still i am getting same issue. please help to correct code

my code

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de, fr, it, en">
        <meta name="author" content="">
```

Comment: could you post the <head> of your file? Did you choose utf-8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 encoded html pages show � (questions marks) instead of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445137/utf-8-encoded-html-pages-show-questions-marks-instead-of-characters)

Comment: i have added head section in question

Comment: i have tried answer not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445137/utf-8-encoded-html-pages-show-questions-marks-instead-of-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have find answer myself

Data comes from db using php server side scripting thats why html meta tag not working but we can do it using php header. please check below one line of code to do it.

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

Comment: this is perfect answer i have put above code and working well

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few possibilities:

Maybe (if you work on a web server) the configuration is wrong. Search for settings about `ISO 8859-1`.

It also could be the configuration of your browser. Check [this topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809931/how-to-force-utf-8-encoding-in-browser). It describes how to force browsers to use UTF-8 using `.htaccess`.

And if everything of this doesn't work you could change every character to the html code with search and replace. This should work without UTF-8.

- Ä = `&Auml;`
- ä = `&auml;`
- Ö = `&Ouml;`
- ö = `&ouml;`
- Ü = `&Uuml;`
- ü = `&uuml;`

I hope you find a solution.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  try this one but still same

Comment: How about the other methods?

Comment: i have display content dynamic from db how can i replace that character using php logic ?