# How to force browser to use UTF-8?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, utf-8

I am having a hard time making an "Í" work! It just keeps appearing me a "É" and I can't figure out why. Curiusly enough, it only happens with capital I, when it is a "í", everything works just fine.

What I have tried so far:

Specify the codification on the head

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Another way on the head

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

with .php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

.htaccess

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
```

Another way on the .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
```

Manualy replace the "Í" for the element

```
&Iacute;
```

Nothing changes and it keeps appearing as "É" instead. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Add  <meta charset="UTF-8">  to your html.

Comment: Have you included `<meta charset="utf-8">` at the _beginning_ of `<head>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809931/how-to-force-utf-8-encoding-in-browser

Is your problem similar to this?

Comment: What's the other side of the equation…? Are you actually ***serving*** UTF-8 encoded text?! Are you using a ***font*** which contains  the correct glyph?

Comment: Yup, that was the problem! Actually, from browser to browser the font-family was changing, and the alternative one doesn't have the glyphs! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in .htaccess

```
php_value default_charset None 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: That's hardly "forcing the browser to use __UTF-8__"…