# Enforce UTF-8 charset for web server

Tags: php, html, http, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to set UTF-8 charset for my web server. Below is the sample header I am sending.

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 / Unauthorized
```

Response header is:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=10.102.147.190
```

But for different browsers I am getting different values:
IE is encoding Latin Character Small E:test as Pzp0ZXN0, chrome as 4bSHOnRlc3Q= and firefox as Bzp0ZXN0

as a result, the username is different when entered from different browsers.
I googled this quite a but, but seems setting the "charset=utf-8" is the only solution, which is not working in my case. let me know how to solve this issue.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have many options : `.htaccess` with `php_value default_charset UTF-8`, + encode all php pages `UTF 8 w/o BOM` + make sure when usind DB to set proper encoding. But if you need ISO somewhere else, that'll put you into troubles... Some reading [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809931/how-to-force-utf-8-encoding-in-browser) and [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-apache) might help, I hope so

Comment: If the question is about character encoding the Basic auth credentials, you may want to look at https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7617.html#charset and hope for this to get implemented in browsers and servers soonish...